# How to call java adapter from javascript adapter?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

How to call java adapter from javascript adapter? In [this tutorial](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/server-side-development/advanced-adapter-usage-mashup/), it only covers:

JavaScript -> JavaScript adapters
Java adapter -> JavaScript adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the option to call a Java adapter from a JavaScript adapter is not supported. You could put the adapter as the endpoint in the JavaScript's XML -> connectionPolicy, but in general this flow is untested and not supported.

Comment: Thx @Idan Adar... got it.